multiple modals for gallery website using HTML CSS JavaScript
Im making a gallery for a website but modals doesnt work for me. i tried everything.
if possible please add two navigation arrows like on messenger or facebook.
my code:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Galéria</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="pics/icon.ico" type="image/x-icon">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Rubik:ital,wght@0,300..900;1,300..900&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>
<body>
    <div class="topnav" id="myTopnav"
        <a href="index.html">Home</a>
        <a href="galery.html">Galéria</a>
        <a href="info.html">Információk</a>
        <a href="javascript:void(0);">
          <i></i>
        </a>
    

    <div id="kepek">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (1).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (2).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (3).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (4).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (5).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (6).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (7).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (8).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (9).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (10).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (11).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (12).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (13).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (14).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (15).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (16).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (17).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (18).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (19).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (20).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (21).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (22).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (23).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (24).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (25).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (26).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (27).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (28).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (29).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (31).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (32).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (33).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (34).jpg" alt="">
      <img class="galleryimg" src="pics/gallery/kep (35).jpg" alt="">
    </div>
    
    
    <script src="app.js"></script>




#kepek {
display: grid;
grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fill, minmax(200px, 1fr));
gap: 20px;
padding: 20px;
}

.galleryimg {
height: 26vh;
width: 100%;
object-fit: cover;
border-radius: 5px;
cursor: pointer;
transition: transform 0.2s;
}

.galleryimg:hover {
transform: scale(1.05);
}



"More details" means what did you try? How did the result differ from your expectation? Are there any error messages? What steps have you taken to debug it?

You tagged javascript, but there's no javascript here, at least not relevant to modals.

Asking question here can be challenging at first. You need to know a bit what we expect. Luckily there's help, see: How do I ask a good question?

Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a minimal reproducible example.

Here is the solid js solution for multiple modals: https://fancyapps.com/fancybox/
Maybe it will give you some clue how to build your own modals on webpage.
Make sure that you check the "Showcase" first

hey can you help me import it to my code? if yes please add me on discord balazs0

Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center.
